# Test SQL Server database doesn't give any error while production database does for an identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have code as shown below in both test and production, however, in test it causes no errors, while in production it throws an error

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '#temptable' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #temptable
(
     id int identity,
     name varchar(1000)
)

-- this 'exampleSP' returns two columns named 'id' and 'name'
INSERT INTO #temptable (id, name)
    EXEC exampleSP @ value1,@value2
```

Is there anything in configuration in QA which is not there in production or vice-versa due to which the error is in production but not in QA

Comment: if your sp returning two values just remove identity from #temptable creation query

Comment: @KetanKotak : Cannot remove the identity column, it needs to remain an identity column. Need to understand what is causing this error in one environment and not in another

Comment: Are you certain `exampleSP ` is identical between environments?

Comment: I can't think of a way that code fragment _wouldn't_ return that error. Are you running exactly this code in both environments in SSMS?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : yes, I am running exactly the same code. It is strange i know but it is happenning. Not sure if there can a difference in any configuration which can cause this.

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that your tables do NOT have the same definition. Surely you have obfuscated and simplified the "code" for posting - you will need to debug the problem yourself. There is no global database setting that will allow direct insertion of values into identity columns.

Comment: @SMor : Thanks, that is what i wanted to understand if there is any global DB setting for inserting records for an identity column. I do have checked and the code is the same for both the environements, however, one doubt remains if there is any difference in output of the code : EXEC exampleSP @ value1,@value2 on both the environments which may cause the issue if there is no output in this in QA(i hope)

Comment: I can't actually reproduce that error message - I'm pretty sure your procs are different. There is no global setting for this, it's session level.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid : Thanks.... The procedures are same as i have checked them with compare in notepad++. But can be some other issue. Thanks though.

Comment: With regards to checking if IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. Only one table can have it on at a time. So if you try and `SET IDENTITY_INSERT [OtherTable] ON` and it's already set for `#temptable`, it will throw an error. In the first instance, use that to work out whether this table has this set or not. It will narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid :  yes, thanks. I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You can set `identity insert on` to insert `id` value .

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [#temptable] ON 
-- insert data
INSERT INTO #temptable (id, name)
EXEC exampleSP @ value1,@value2
-- set off again if you want
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [#temptable] OFF
```

`identity` meant to have default `auto increment` `int` value. If you do not want that then you need to set `identity insert on`.

Comment: hi, thanks, yes i can have identity insert on...but my main concern is that the same code is throwing error in one environment and in the other it works fine. why is it happening so ? it should either throw error in both the environments or should work fine in both

Comment: I am not sure but I think it is not possible to insert in identity column without setting `identity_insert on` . Is your table is temporary ? If you creating your table every time you run the code and  drop again then i am not sure what is the problem here. But if it is permanent table then i guess in QA `identity insert is already ON`

Comment: can identity insert be set to on from SSMS(Sql server magmt studio) and not from the code ?

Comment: I am 99% certain, no. Unless there is some kind of trigger at play\. I did some research and interestingly there is no way to establish whether `SET IDENTITY_INSERT` is currently on